# when we have written text in capital letter text-transform capitalize css not working correctly

Tags: html, css

I'm currently working on a project where I've applied the `text-transform: capitalize;` property to a specific class (`div.c`), but it doesn't seem to be working as expected when the text is in all capital letters.
Here's a snippet of the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
div.c {
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h2>text-transform: capitalize:</h2>
<div class="c">THIS IS TESTING CONTENT</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set text-transform: capitalize;, it capitalizes the first letter of each word in the text.

if you have pre-written the text in capital letter than that "capitalize" will have no effect.

Comment: But in my project already some text are capital, That's why I  want to change the text using css. It is not possible to change all the text manually. So what is the alternative way?

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <style>
    .capitalize {
      text-transform: capitalize;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="capitalize" id="capitalizeMe">
    THIS IS SOME TEXT
  </div>

  <script>
    var element = document.getElementById('capitalizeMe');
    element.textContent = element.textContent.toLowerCase().replace(/\b\w/g, function (word) {
      return word.toUpperCase();
    });
  </script>

</body>
</html>

Answer (score 1):

We can't apply `capitalize` when all letter are in `uppercase`

**You can almost do it with:**

```
.c {
  text-transform: lowercase;
}
.c:first-letter, .c:first-line {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

**OR**
You can also do it with **JavaScript**

```
Convert with JavaScript using .toLowerCase() and capitalize would do the rest.
```

Answer (score 1):

span,
a,
h2{

text-transform:lowercase

}

span:first-letter, a:first-letter, h2:first-letter
{

text-transform: capitalize;

}

Comment: You can improve your answer by giving little bit of explanation, and doing some [formatting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks).